# What does is mean to have input from multiple wallet addresses?

Tags: transactions, transaction-input

I've trying to parse some data from the blockchain as provided by blockchain.info

My question is about transactions that have multiple inputs like this one:

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/0370881edfb32d3a7059bbbec6d923add2e016c41cdc9abafd1f1c52adf3ac9e

What does is mean to have input from multiple wallet addresses?

- Are each of the wallets mentioned on the left hand side here always from the same *person* (ie. perhaps *change* wallets)?
- Or, is this transaction taking inputs from multiple (unrelated) people/wallets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are each of the wallets mentioned on the left hand side here always from the same person (ie. perhaps change wallets)?
>
> Or, is this transaction taking inputs from multiple (unrelated) people/wallets?

It could be either. A single user's wallet might consume many UTXOs when crafting a transaction, but it is also possible for two (or more) people to supply inputs to a transaction, and they can do so without having to trust one another. So a transaction could have many potential participants, on the input side, and output side.

See:

- Common input ownership heuristic info: [1,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/clustering-addresses-whats-the-most-effective-way/49408#49408) [2.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/batching-transactions-to-safe-on-fees/85975#85975)
- [Coinjoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/explain-how-coinjoin-enhances-anonymity-in-plain-english/19163#19163)
- [BIP 174 - partially signed bitcoin transactions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83070/expected-use-model-for-psbt) - [Full BIP 174 text](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki)
- In depth info: [Bitcoin Privacy Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy)